# nginx rewrite rule conflict

Tags: caching, nginx, url-rewriting

I am having a conflict with two blocks with nginx 1.8.0.

The first block is to setup static cache for certain file types:

```
location ~* \.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|swf)$ {
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  expires max;
}
```

The second block is a series of rewrites defined by filetype:

```
location /files {
rewrite ^/files/master\.([0-9]+)?\.css$ /min/?g=css&456 break;
rewrite ^/files/master\.([0-9]+)?\.js$ /min/?g=js&456 break;
rewrite ^/files/second\.([0-9]+)?\.js$ /min/?g=jsa&456 break;
}
```

The rewrites result in a 404. Any rewrite that uses a filetype defined in the static cache rule results in a 404 error. If I change the rewrite rule to a different filetype or comment out the static cache file block, it works.

What am I missing in the cache static files that is preventing a rewrite from being performed at a later config setting?

Answer (score 0):

After much gnashing of teeth, I ended up changing the redirects to a try_files parameter. The parameters must be higher in the conf file than the static cache file.

```
location ~ ^/files/master\.([0-9]+)?\.css$ {
   try_files $uri /min/?g=css&456;
}   
location ~ ^/files/master\.([0-9]+)?\.js$ {
   try_files $uri /min/?g=js&456;
} 
location ~ ^/files/second\.([0-9]+)?\.js$ {
   try_files $uri /min/?g=jsa&456;
}
```

This will allow me to run the minify toolset.